# Adding C++ kernels to Jupyter notebook

Tags: c++, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

After successful installation of cling, I tried to add c++ kernels to jupyter notebook but it says my kernel appears to have died and it keeps restarting with the following error message:

The 'stdin_port' trait of an IPKernelApp instance must be an integer, but a value of u'c++11'  was specified.

I am using Python2.7 and macOS

Regards,

Comment: Could you please show an appropriate `kernel.json`?