# cling kernel for jupyter on MacBook Air

Tags: python, c++, macos, jupyter, cling

I built cling on my MacBook Air(Mid2013, macOS10.12.4).
My jupyter version is 4.3.0.

I followed instructions on https://github.com/vgvassilev/cling/tree/master/tools/Jupyter and the installation ended without an error.

However, when I tried to make a new ipynb with c++(17, 14, 11) kernels, I got the following

```
[IPKernelApp] CRITICAL | Bad config encountered during initialization:
[IPKernelApp] CRITICAL | The 'stdin_port' trait of an IPKernelApp instance must be an int, but a value of 'c++17' <class 'str'> was specified.
```

I went to https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/options/kernel.html and checked item 'IPKernelApp.stdin_port', and understood (I think so) the literal meaing of the error, but I didn't know how to fix it.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I think there are similar problems reported. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43899636/dead-kernel-anaconda-jupyter-cling-c-windows

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459809/adding-c-kernels-to-jupyter-notebook?rq=1